# Decorating class having methods internally calling each other

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have a class `IMessageProcessor`

```
public interface IMessageProcessor{
   Task ProcessMessages();
   Task ProcessMessage(Message message);
}
```

with simplified implementation:

```
public class MessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor {
   public async Task ProcessMessages(){
      ...
      foreach (Message message in messages){
         await ProcessMessage(message)
      }
      ...
   }

   public Task ProcessMessage(Message message){
      // processing message
   }
}
```

I have also implemented decorator to be kind of error interceptor/handler:

```
public class ErrorHandlerDecorator : IMessageProcessor {
   IMessageProcessor decorated;

   public async Task ProcessMessages(){
      try{
         decorated.ProcessMessages();
      }
      catch{
         // exception handling logic
      }
   }

   public Task ProcessMessage(Message message){
      try{
         decorated.ProcessMessage(message);
      }
      catch{
         // other exception handling logic (retries etc.)
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is when I call `ProcessMessages` and hitting `ProcessMessage` method, my decorated `ProcessMessage` error handling logic is not executed as I call it directly on `MessageProcessor` instance.

Is this possible to somehow make decorator works when I call some methods internally in decorated class?

Thanks

Comment: If MessageProcessor does not catch exceptions, they will automatically bubble up to the caller, i.e., your decorator. On the other hand, if you are catching exceptions in MessageProcessor then you can rethrow them to give the decorator the chance to catch them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface is not well suited for decoration. You should probably move `Task ProcessMessages();` to some other class.

It is unclear where `messages` comes from, or what is adding the messages. But if the class is named `IMessageProcessor` there is a good chance it should chance it should take messages as *input*, do some processing, and possibly return a result.

If there is something that buffers messages in a queue for later processing there should be a separate class, like `MessageQueue`, where messages can be enqueued for later processing.

Also note that your decorator should most likely await the task from the decorated processor. Not doing this would be quite unexpected for most developers, and could result in all kinds of nasty bugs.